# Is "could use" rude?

Tags: politeness

Is "could use" considered rude?

For example:

"We could use some extra information"

"For this task we could use some help from..."

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly not rude or impolite but you would be better served using something a little more formal like:

"For this task we could benefit from some help from...."

Comment: Thank you very much. I cannot upvote you because I have not enough reputation. :-(

Comment: @ordago You do now!

Comment: I'm at 13, I need 15 points :-)

Comment: Now I can, upvoted :-)